# Combo box Where Clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, where-clause

i have a table of POMain po_no and a table of Shipping invoice, then when i search the po_no, i will add an invoice. the thing i want to do is if the po_no already have an invoice the po_no in search button will not appear

```
public AddForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    string ID = cb_po_search.SelectedValue.ToString();
                string strPRSconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POSdb"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(strPRSconn);
                sc.Open();
                string strQry = "SELECT POMain.po_no FROM POMain LEFT JOIN Shipping ON POMain.po_no = Shipping.po_no WHERE Shipping.invoice IS NULL AND POMain.po_no = '" + ID + "'";
                SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strQry, sc);
                SqlDataReader dr = scmd.ExecuteReader();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("po_no", typeof(string));
                dt.Load(dr);

                cb_po_search.ValueMember = "po_no";
                cb_po_search.DisplayMember = "po_no";
                cb_po_search.DataSource = dt;

                sc.Close();

            }

            }
```

Comment: sorry sir can u understand now?

Comment: ahm yes i just want to know what do i code in where clause that if the invoice have a value the po_no will not appear in the combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT OUTER join here instead of an INNER join

`string strQry ="SELECT POMain.po_no FROM POMain INNER JOIN Shipping ON POMain.po_no = Shipping.po_no WHERE Shipping.invoice IS NULL";`

And you need to add another condition to the WHERE clause at the end:

`AND POMain.po_no = " + ID`

Having said that, you would be much better off using a stored procedure instead of trying to form an inline query.

Comment: string strQry = "SELECT POMain.po_no FROM POMain LEFT JOIN ON Shipping POMain.po_no = Shipping.po_no WHERE Shipping.invoice IS NULL";

Comment: string strQry = "SELECT POMain.po_no FROM POMain LEFT JOIN Shipping ON POMain.po_no = Shipping.po_no WHERE Shipping.invoice IS NULL AND POMain.po_no = " + ID;

Comment: incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON' i got this error

Comment: change `ON Shipping` to `Shipping ON`

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Hope you are executing this query in the `cb_po_search_SelectedIndexChanged` method, coz that's where you get the ID.

Comment: so, on which line are you getting the null reference exception now?

Comment: i think this line string strQry = "SELECT POMain.po_no FROM POMain LEFT JOIN Shipping ON POMain.po_no = Shipping.po_no WHERE Shipping.invoice IS NULL AND POMain.po_no = '" + ID + "'";

Comment: think? please find out the exact line using a debugger or an error logger.

the line you mention is just concatenating strings. it cant be the one throwing this exception.

Comment: no line sir just this "
 
object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: What debugger do you use that doesnt allow you to find out the line number from which the exception originated?
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) about Exception.StackTrace:
The stack trace listing provides a way to follow the call stack to the line number in the method where the exception occurs.

Comment: You are probably getting an exception because `cb_po_search` is not initialized in the form's constructor. Please move all code except `InitializeComponent` to an event handler.

Comment: thanks sir no error for now. but in my search text not appearing any data